# NightWatchJS - Login page - How to test that password is masked

Tags: automated-tests, nightwatch.js

Does anyone know how I could test that when a user enters a password into the password field of a login page that the password is masked (asterisk'd out)? I tried using 'getValue' on the password input box, but it is just returns the entered password, see below:-

```
'Password is masked when entered into login page' : function(browser) {
    let testPassword;
    loginPageObject.setUsername("MOCKUSERNAME");
    loginPageObject.setPassword("TESTPASSWORD");

    browser.getValue(loginPageObject.elements.password, function(result) {
      testPassword = result;
      console.log("**************");
      console.log("PASSWORD");
      console.log(testPassword);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought about the issue and came to the conclusion that the following line of code would suffice, as knowing that the input type is of type 'password' would be enough to ensure that the entered password is not visible when entered into a field of this type.

```
browser.assert.attributeEquals(loginPageObject.elements.password, 'type', 'password');
```